# While Loop- Continue Statement printing duplicate values

Tags: python, while-loop, continue

I am writing the following code in Python to execute a program that 'skips' out numbers in a range of 1-10 which are divisible by 3:

```py
for i in range(10):
    while i % 3 == 0 :
        i = i + 1
        continue
    print(i)
```

BUT,

the output is printing out duplicate values:

```
1
1
2
4
4
5
7
7
8
10
```

Can someone please explain the error in the code?
Thanks.

A program that 'skips' out numbers in a range of 1-10 which are divisible by 3:

```py
for i in range(10):
    while i % 3 == 0 :
        i = i + 1
        continue
    print(i)
```

OUTPUT:

```
0
1
2
4
5
7
8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question states numbers from range 1 to 10 then it rules out 0 as a response in answer also the answer by @Piyush is correct but you should look more into loops and check how they work as for and while can be used **together** but in different scenarios and not like the range of numbers asked by you.

Answer (score 0):

Correct code to do the required operation is mentioned below, please see if this solves your purpose.

```py
for i in range(10): 
    if i % 3 == 0: 
        continue
    print(I)
```